# Is there any Stack Exchange website useful to request a programming book/site?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, off-topic

I'd like to ask about a programming book (no specific book: I'd like recommendations for a good book). Stack Overflow seems to treat these topics as off-topic (since it does not involve a particular problem solving). However, some sites do have identification requests or stuff alike (for example, [manga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manga) and [anime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anime)).

Where can I ask for such type of recommendations without asking an off-topic question? (topics: books about/teaching a programming language).

**Clarify**: No. My intention is not to ask about illegal books downloads, only titles.

Comment: 1) go to amazon.com 2) search for books based on the subject you want to learn about 3) sort by user reviews 4) look for a book that has many reviews that are mostly 5 stars 5) read description of book, look inside if offered, read a review or two 6) if not yet convinced, ask a question in regards to your misgivings 7) buy the book

Answer (score 9):

Identification requests are not recommendation requests (in particular, for Anime & Manga, this is for identifying a work by some description of it - i.e. "I remember seeing this film 15 years ago, these things happened in it, what is it?" - that's not a recommendation).

We have two Stack Exchange sites that accept recommendations (with very specific limitations):

- [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com); and
- [Hardware Recommendations](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

Currently, there is no Stack Exchange site where you can ask for programming book recommendations.

Comment: "We currently have one site that does recommendations" >> What site does SE have?

Comment: I did say. Software Recommendations.

Comment: And hardware recommendations also.

Comment: I'm sorry. Did not understand that was a title.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this question won't fit [any site of SE network](https://stackexchange.com/sites). Try asking it in the chat of, say, Stack Overflow.

The chat rooms also do have some sort of scope, so search for the rooms and find the appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. You deserve more "+1"s

Answer (score 1):

I just figured I would add...

There is a proposal on Area 51 that might be of interest: [Book Recommendations](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/87408/book-recommendations). As the description reads:

> Proposed Q&A site for people seeking recommendations for books to read given a stated interest in authors, topics, themes, moods, settings, characters, and/or other criteria.

Comment: It's already dead with on any alternative.