# What's wrong with questions regarding appropriate SE websites?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

There are times when we ask for an appropriate SE site for certain activities (e.g. don't know if certain question fits in Security vs Superuser, Security vs Tor, stackoverflow vs code review, ...) perhaps because we cannot decide which known site to use, or we just don't know which site of the huge SE network fits our needs.

I recall some day asking a question about an SE website to ask about laws. That question was immediately downvoted, several times. Answers to my question (it seems i deleted it in order to not keep adding negative votes) included expressions which were reasonable, like "don't ask about laws on Internet; ask your lawyer for that stuff". [Some time later it happened that such website exists](https://law.stackexchange.com/).

Some days ago [I asked about a SE website for books recommendations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269159/is-there-any-stack-exchange-website-useful-to-request-a-programming-book-site) and a user answered telling it was a yet-Area51 project.

Both questions got downvoted (at this moment the latter is at 0 balance), and I cannot avoid noticing (or suspecting) a kind of pattern here.

**Q**: What's wrong about asking about SE websites in **this** general META site? Is that kind of questions somehow off-topic?

Comment: There's an entire tag here for [site recommendations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation)... it's part of the reason that Meta is here. I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Users tend to downvote the questions when they've been asked repeatedly many, many times before.

Comment: You understood it perfectly. I was downvoted on question regarding website recommendations.

Comment: @animuson how's about getting search fixed so it's easier to close->dupe something than it is to write your own answer and|or downvote. Finding the dupe you know exists is stupidly difficult.

Comment: I added a tag for [tag:site-recommendation] because, even though this is not asking for a specific site recommendation, that will help group it with them when others are looking for where to ask about site recommendations.

Answer (score 9):

> What's wrong about asking about SE websites in this general META site? Is that kind of questions somehow off-topic?

Nothing is wrong with that. Those kind of questions are on topic here, and [we have 1,136 of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation).

That said, [animuson is right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269363/whats-wrong-with-questions-regarding-appropriate-se-websites#comment872809_269363):

> Users tend to downvote the questions when they've been asked repeatedly many, many times before. – animuson ♦

It's a good idea to do a thorough search before posting here - folks *do* tend to get tired of seeing the same question over and over. Another thing: **voting is <s>different</s> weird on meta**. People downvote for all kinds of reasons... some of them bad reasons.

Ask yourself why your post was downvoted, then move on. It's definitely not anything to worry about.